# How do I pass a specific value from getUser json to my POST axios call as player_one_name?

Tags: javascript, html, json, axios

I'm implementing passing data to DB from function `createGame()`. I'm doing a POST Axios call and for one of the parameters "player_one_name" I want to pass in that specific player's id from DB.

The function `getUser()` prints to console the player id from database. How do I pass this in createGame Axios -> from my json array in `getUser()` correctly?

I've already tried player_one_name: `getUser()`

```
const getUser = () => {
  var json;
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/hrender', true);
    request.send();
    request.onload=function(){
        json=JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        //prints player ID from user info.
        console.log(json);

      };
};


const createGame = async(room_name) => {

  console.log(room_name)
  try{
    const res = await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/game/createGame',
      data: {
          // player_one_name: player_one_name,
          room_name: room_name
      }
    });
console.log(res);
if (res.status == 201) {
    console.log("created game!")
    document.location.href= "/play.html"  
}
} catch (error){
alert("game not created!");
}

};


document.getElementById('createGame').addEventListener('submit', e =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    //Need playerID from getUser to be stored as player_one_name here..
  //  const player_one_name = playerid;
    const room_name  = document.getElementById('room_name').value;
  createGame(room_name);
  }); 

json result of getUser() ...

{_id: "5d429421b82ecb2c44c58309", name: "bb", email: "b@b.com", __v: 0}
email: "b@b.com"
name: "bb"
__v: 0
_id: "5d429421b82ecb2c44c58309"
}
```

route axios is passed to in database ...

```
exports.createGame = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) =>{
const newGame = await Game.create({
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    player_one_name: req.body.player_one_name,
    player_one_side: 'Black',
    player_two_side: 'White',
    room_name: req.body.room_name,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are missing async await on getUser() because it also as API call.

More about using Async Await

```
https://javascript.info/async-await
```

Solution to a similar problem, mentioned in above sites examples:

```js
async function showAvatar() {

  // read our JSON
  let response = await fetch('/article/promise-chaining/user.json');
  let user = await response.json();

  // read github user
  let githubResponse = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user.name}`);
  let githubUser = await githubResponse.json();
  
  }
```